# Managing Interface Orientation ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation, interface-orientation

I am facing some problems with my current application's interface orientation. My application need to run only in portrait orientation But I need to show the videos in both modes. So what I have done is I set the application to support all orientations both portrait and land scape in the project file. And in my view controller class (a base class for all view controllers in the project) I set the status bar orientation to portrait. It works perfectly for all view controllers except for that presented as modal view . Any solution for restricting land scape mode to those views??

Comment: Posting the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869570/managing-interface-orientation-ios-6) has no meaning.

Comment: It ws by mistake. Thanks for notifying

Comment: hi, are you presenting the view controller in which you want to display video????

Comment: @NiravPatel no. I am playing video in some other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `custom class` files subclass of `UINavigationController` to support rotation as per your requirement.

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466048/how-to-allow-only-single-uiviewcontroller-to-rotate-in-both-landscape-and-portra) . Please follow it, you will get an idea.

Hope this will help.