# Rotate only one view controller in ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a storyboard with more than 50 view controllers. Among this 50 view controllers I have to rotate only one view controller to landscape mode because it contains a UIWebview. My app only supports portrait mode.I have tried the following code, but it's crashing.

Is there any possibility to do with App delegate...Please help.

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
 }
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466048/how-to-allow-only-single-uiviewcontroller-to-rotate-in-both-landscape-and-portra

Answer (score -2):

Try to rotate using view.transform property.

Comment: @Andrea : Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The link posted by Ganesh can give you a lot of inputs to find the solution, but this answer in particular is completely wrong.