# How to change rotation of icons in landscape mode in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

Currently my App looks like this in portrait mode:
[image]

but when my iPad is in landscape mode I want my Icons look like this:
[image]

By now it looks like that in landscape mode:

[image]

I know how to rotate the icons but I don't know where I have to paste the code. I just want to look my app in landscape mode like the 2nd pic.

> EDIT

It should look like this one:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

you need to set observer using  NSNotificationCenter following code

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationChnaged", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

in AppDelegate *didFinishedLaunching* method.

And in observer method you check for orientation

```
if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
{            
    print("landscape")
}

if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
{
    print("Portrait")
}
```

Comment: Also you can do this code in any UIViewController viewDidLoad method and add observer for same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rotate your `yourimageview` by 90 degree in landscape mode -

In AppDelegate.swift inside the `"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"` function I put:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and then inside the `AppDelegate` class I put the following function:

```
     func rotated()
        {
            if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
            {            
                print("landscape")
             //Rotate 90 degrees clockwise:        
               yourimageview1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))         
            //Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise:        
             yourimageview2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
            }
            if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
            {
                print("Portrait")
            }

        }
```

Hope this helps anyone else!

Answer (score 1):

You should manage it from `Assets` if your `deployment target` is equal or greater than `8.0`. You can set different images for different size class. For example for Portrait mode in iphone you can set assset for`Compact width Regular Height` size class and for iphones in landscape you can set asset for `Any width Compact Height` size class.

Refer apple documentation for [Customizing Assets for Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CustomizingImageSetsforSizeClasses.html)

Comment: Is there a way to override the rotation. My app rotates automatically and then it looks like the 3rd picture I posted and not like the 2nd

Comment: If you set different picture for landscape and portrait then it will automatically take it for respective orientation. You not need to do anything programmatically.

Comment: Why a different picture?! Above I posted the picture how it actually looks like and what I want it to look like

Comment: Second thing it should be done by auto layout.If you set proper constraints then it will automatically adjust in landscape and portrait.

Comment: And how could I set the constraints so they work for landscape and portrait mode? In portrait the icons height is view.height/2 and in landscape too as you can see on the 3rd picture. How can I solve that?

Comment: look I've edited my post so you could probably understand it better

Comment: Other answers have already mentioned that how to handle rotations so go likewise!

Answer (score 0):

Try as following in your **ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationChnaged", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}


- (void) deviceOrientationChnaged:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {            
        print("landscape")
       yourimageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))

      //OR Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise:

       yourimageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

**EDIT:**

Please check my this question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466048/how-to-allow-only-single-uiviewcontroller-to-rotate-in-both-landscape-and-portra)

Comment: I've edited my post for better understanding. Maybe you know what should be done?

Comment: @mafioso I think you are talking about supporting your app for Landscape mode.

Comment: It is supported in landscape mode but the icons look like the 3rd picture and I want them to look like the 4th picture

Comment: In your answer the icons look like I want but the view isn't in landscape mode. How can I combine that?