# Support landscape and portrait orientation for UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

The orientation of my IOS app has been locked to Portrait mode. However, I want to support both landscape and portrait orientation for files that open using UIDocumentInteractionController.
Here is my code to open a file url.

```
 let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: fileURL)
        self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: url)
        documentController!.delegate = self
        documentController!.presentPreview(animated: false)
```

How do I achieve portrait and landscape orientation for files that open using the above code while also locking down the orientation to portrait for other screens?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Override supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutoRotate:

[How to allow only single UIViewController to rotate in both Landscape and Portrait direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466048/how-to-allow-only-single-uiviewcontroller-to-rotate-in-both-landscape-and-portra). Swift 3 Kosher Version