# Launching app in landscape distorts entire app, when disabling landscape orientation in certain controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, screen-orientation

I'm utilizing a navigation controller in my app. I want all of my viewController to be in portrait only except for one, which will support landscape.

Going with an accepted answer in Stack Overflow I subclassed my nav controller and include this code:

[iOS 6 - Navigation Controller Landscape Rotations For Some Views While Others Portrait Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989353/ios-6-navigation-controller-landscape-rotations-for-some-views-while-others-po)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    id currentViewController = self.topViewController;

    if ([currentViewController isKindOfClass:[IssueViewController class]])
    return YES;

    return NO;
  }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; 
 }
```

This singles out the one view controller I would like to rotate. Everything works great except when I launch the app in landscape. The image gets crushed and off centered.

screen shots here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCkne.jpg

Any suggestions on correcting this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code. This works fine only when you change the orientation, but it doesn't reflect changes according to current interface orientation if you launch the app in landscape or go from one to other controller in landscape.

Use the following approach, which I have used to solve same kind of issue some time ago.

Add this code in UINavigationController subclass

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

And in you ViewController, add this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  //Control UIInterfaceOrientationMask here to tell which interface orientations you want to support for this ViewController
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```